# What are the difference between "Tweets" formats and its decode/encode via python?

Tags: python, json, twitter, arabic

**Hello,**

Using Python 2.7 & Tweepy Library

Main topic: Downloading tweets from Streaming API using Python.

I am confused about different formats of downloaded tweets from Streaming API, as formatting differentiate from one to another of the same tweet !!

Note: I am concerning only in Arabic Tweets.

**1st format is:**

*{"created_at":"Wed Feb 03 12:52:53 +0000 2016","id":694866144142848001,"id_str":"694866144142848001","text":"\u06 ………*

**Used Code of 1st format:**

```
import tweepy
import json
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
  def on_data(self, data):
     print(data)
     file.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
#OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    listener = StdOutListener()
    stream = Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter( track=[u'الى' , u'إلى' ,u'عشان',u'علشان',u'ماشى',u'ليه',u'ازاى'])
```

============================================

**2nd format is:**

*{u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'\u0627', u'is_quote_status': False,….*

**Used Code of 2nd:**

```
def on_data(self, data):
    print json.loads(data)
```

> Note: Error when writing json.loads(data) in a file

=================================================

**3rd format is:**

*{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "RT @a_meles: @EHSANFAKEEH\n\u0627 ", "is_quote_status": false, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "id": 695174171903582208, "favorite_count": 0, "source": "http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter f……*

**Used Code of 3rd format:**

```
def on_data(self, data):
    x = json.loads(data)        
    print (json.dumps(x))
```

================================================

**4th format is:**

*Status(contributors=None, truncated=False, text=u'@AlsaeedFajer \u0627\ ', is_quote_status=False, in_reply_to_status_id=None, id=694494200520413184L, favorite_count=0, _api=, author=User(follow_request_sent=None, profile_use_background_image=True, _json={u'follow_reques……….*

**Used code of 4th format:** used on_status instead of on_data

```
def on_status(self, status):
            print status
```

============================================

Then, which is the familiar way to extract tweet text and write in a file without problems??

**Thanks for your efforts,**

Answer (score 0):

[An Answer for the same question](https://twittercommunity.com/t/what-are-the-difference-between-tweets-downloaded-formats-and-its-decode-encode-via-python/61009/2?u=moh)

> Ideally, you want to work with & store JSON objects as they are sent to you from Twitter:
>
> 1st format: on_data method of a stream listener receives all messages:
>   see
>   https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/docs/streaming_how_to.rst1
>   This may or may not be what you want to store in a file for later.
>
> 2nd format: print json.loads(data) prints the string representation of
>   the Python object you create with .loads (it's usually a dict)
>
> 3rd format: result is almost the same as 1st - but you are
>   Deserializing a json object from a string, then Serializing it
>   straight away. Difference between 1st and 3rd: the order of fields
>   like "created_at", "id" sometimes changes depending on the library.
>
> 4th format is a string representation of a Status Python object:
>   tweepy Status object is not JSON, but it has a _json property which
>   contains the JSON response from twitter.
>
> It should work if you use on_status() listener, storing the
>   status._json in a file for later (not the status object itself)
>
> Hope that helps!

This is not my answer, I just added the link to spread the knowledge.
Thanks for him.